# Packets are not getting received at other interface

Tags: wireshark, packet, mininet

I have a script which consists of 2 switches 2 hosts which are in different subnet connected to a single router. When I send packets from 1 host to the other packets are not getting received at another interface, I am using Wireshark at the other interface for the confirmation but no packets have arrived. Attaching the code and screenshot of the topology. Any help regarding this will be great.

The topology is like this
H1----S1-----R------S2------H2

```
from mininet.net import Mininet

from mininet.node import Controller, RemoteController,OVSKernelSwitch, UserSwitch

from mininet.cli import CLI

from mininet.log import setLogLevel

from mininet.link import Link, TCLink



def topology():

net = Mininet( controller=RemoteController, link=TCLink, switch=OVSKernelSwitch )



    # Add hosts and switches

    h1 = net.addHost( 'h1', ip="10.0.1.10/24", mac="00:00:00:00:00:01" )

    h2 = net.addHost( 'h2', ip="10.0.2.10/24", mac="00:00:00:00:00:02" )

    r1 = net.addHost( 'r1')

    s1 = net.addSwitch( 's1')

    s2 = net.addSwitch( 's2')

    c0 = net.addController( 'c0', controller=RemoteController, ip='127.0.0.1', port=6633 )



    net.addLink( r1, s1 )

    net.addLink( r1, s2 )

    net.addLink( h1, s1 )

    net.addLink( h2, s2 )

    net.build()

    c0.start()

    s1.start( [c0] )

    s2.start( [c0] )

    r1.cmd("ifconfig r1-eth0 0")

    r1.cmd("ifconfig r1-eth1 0")

    r1.cmd("ifconfig r1-eth0 hw ether 00:00:00:00:01:01")

    r1.cmd("ifconfig r1-eth1 hw ether 00:00:00:00:01:02")

    r1.cmd("ip addr add 10.0.1.1/24 brd + dev r1-eth0")

    r1.cmd("ip addr add 10.0.2.1/24 brd + dev r1-eth1")

    r1.cmd("echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward")

    h1.cmd("ip route add default via 10.0.1.1")

    h2.cmd("ip route add default via 10.0.2.1")

    s1.cmd("ovs-ofctl add-flow s1 priority=1,arp,actions=flood")

    s1.cmd("ovs-ofctl add-flow s1 priority=65535,ip,dl_dst=00:00:00:00:01:01,actions=output:1")

    s1.cmd("ovs-ofctl add-flow s1 priority=10,ip,nw_dst=10.0.1.0/24,actions=output:2")

    s2.cmd("ovs-ofctl add-flow s2 priority=1,arp,actions=flood")

    s2.cmd("ovs-ofctl add-flow s2 priority=65535,ip,dl_dst=00:00:00:00:01:02,actions=output:1")

    s2.cmd("ovs-ofctl add-flow s2 priority=10,ip,nw_dst=10.0.2.0/24,actions=output:2")



    print "*** Running CLI"

    CLI( net )



    print "*** Stopping network"

    net.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    setLogLevel( 'info' )

    topology()
```

Comment: The two hosts are in different subnet.

Comment: This looks like *"Case 2"* from http://csie.nqu.edu.tw/smallko/sdn/mininet_simple_router.htm.  Have you tried contacting Dr. Chih-Heng Ke for help?  The version of python used isn't mentioned, so maybe there's some python difference?

Comment: ok, I will try to contact him.